# r in Jupyter Notebook: lavaan summary output not formatted correctly

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, r-lavaan

I use r in Jupyter Notebook. I was re-running old confirmatory factor analysis (CFA) code and recently I have no longer been able to see accurately see the summary() output in it's normal format. Instead it is in the variable "$variable_name" format. How do I make the summary output appear in its normal format?

This does not occur in rStudio. My r, Jupyter Notebook, and computer software are all up-to-date. The issue occurs with or without me adding "lavaan::" to the beginning of the function. I have also tried reverting to older lavaan versions.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Below is example code.

```
visual =~ x1 + x2 + x3
textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
speed =~ x7 + x8 + x9

HS.model <- ' visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
              speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9 '

fit <- cfa(HS.model, data = HolzingerSwineford1939)

summary(fit, fit.measures = TRUE) 


Output:

$header
$lavaan.version
'0.6-12'
$sam.approach
FALSE
$optim.method
'nlminb'
$optim.iterations
67
$optim.converged
TRUE
$optim
$estimator
'ML'
$estimator.args
$optim.method
'nlminb'
$npar
127
$eq.constraints
FALSE
$nrow.ceq.jac
0
$nrow.cin.jac
0
$nrow.con.jac
0
$con.jac.rank
0
$data
...
```

Comment: `lavaan`'s `summary()` is not meant to be used like this.  It simply prints (in a nicer-looking default way) information that can be obtained elsewhere.  For instance, you can obtain the nice-looking output from `paramterEstimates(fit, output = "pretty")` and `fitMeasures(fit, output = "pretty")`.  the `summary()` method creates an internal object to simultaneously print the many sources of information at once, but it's structure is subject to change, so it is wise not rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a summary():
`print(summary(fit, fit.measures = TRUE) )`
This kind of error can happen on apple silicon mac